# Naming conventions. Method or variable names containing numbers as a words

Tags: naming-conventions, naming, variable-names, method-names

I can't find even couple of words about containing numbers in names of variables or on methods. Does anyone have any authoritative information about such cases:

- string2map
- its4me
- etc...
  Exactly using number as a word but not number as a number.
  Is it acceptable? Not acceptable, stupidly, professional or not. Please argue your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any information either but below are my own thoughts.

Using a digit in an identifier which happens 2 be pronounced in the same way as a word is just silly word play. It also makes the meaning of the identifier ambiguous - does *char2old* mean that a character is too old, is it an old version of *char2* or is it a conversion? It's fun however to come up with names like *a10sorFlow*, *the2lbox*, *my4mula* but they are best avoided.

When it comes to using numbers 1 to *N* at the end of equally named identifiers, it is probably better to use an array instead if *N* > 2. Also, when *N* = 2 there are often clearer names that can be used, like *leftCircle* and *rightCircle* instead of *circle1* and *circle2*, or *currentChar* and *nextChar* instead of *char1* and *char2*.

Here is a good general guide for naming variables:

| Identifier kind | Word class | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boolean variable or pure function | Last word is an ***adjective*** | *doorClosed*, *TablePrepared* |
| Non-boolean variable or pure function | Last word is a ***noun*** | *closedDoor*, *PreparedTable* |
| Non-pure function (has side-effects) | First word is a ***verb*** | *CloseDoor*, *PrepareTable* |

Comment: I completely agree with you. Thanks!